# Eclipse, shortcut to navigate, jumping by multiple lines

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut that allows me to navigate up or down by some number of lines (in Emacs I can jump by # lines by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>).  Does such a shortcut exist?  Currently, I can only move by one line at a time using the arrow keys.  The closest shortcut I'm aware of is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> which jumps to the next function definition (at least in PyDev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own shortcuts under `window > preferences > general > keys`.

In addition, you can switch to an Emacs scheme in that same window.

[image]

However, as far as I know you won't get what you are looking for just by switching to the Emacs schema. For the ability to jump lines like `C-u 10 C-p` you will need the `Emacs+ plugin` found [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs).

Also note you can jump to lines by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't able to find a 'jump by 5 lines' or 'skip by 10 lines' or anything similar under the list of commands to which bind shortcuts.  What should I be looking for?  I know about Control-L, but I was hoping for something even simpler, where I don't have to specify a line number.  I just want to navigate up and down more quickly.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a great extension I didn't know about.  I was actually able to achieve behavior almost like what I wanted using the default Scheme by binding 'forward paragraph' and 'backward paragraph' to Control+Arrow.

Answer (score 2):

with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> you can enter the line number you want to navigate